# Ace Editor is not resizing with the container div

Tags: html, css, ace-editor

I have container div 'myeditor' and I'm adding an ace editor to that div using:

```
var editor = ace.edit('myeditor');
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/terminal");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/sql");
editor.getSession().setUseWrapMode(true);
```

Editor looks like this:
[image]

As shown in the above example it is not taking the full width of the container and the black line is coming on the right.

Here, the container is resizable.
How can I resize ace editor to fit container whenever the container is resized?

Following is the structure of elements:
[image]

There is the main div which has a gutter to expand the div horizontally, which expands inner div as well. Inner div is 'myeditor'.
I am not able to share code as it is an internal project.

Comment: Is the container resizable itself or it is being resized when the whole window is resized?

Comment: I have main div which is expandable. 'myeditor'  div is Inside that div.

Comment: Your main issue is to detect the container resize event. If you did that then `editor.resize()` can reset the editor size.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be referring to the print margin line. If that's the case, you can disable it by using `editor.setShowPrintMargin(false);`.

Example:

```js
var editor = ace.edit('myeditor');
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/terminal");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/sql");
editor.getSession().setUseWrapMode(true);
editor.setShowPrintMargin(false);
```

```css
#myeditor {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.4/ace.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.4/theme-terminal.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  Editor is below.
  <div id="myeditor">
  </div>
</div>
```

Otherwise, I can't seem to reproduce your issue. If you aren't referring to the print margin line, can you include your HTML?

Comment: I am able to hide black line using editor.setShowPrintMargin(false). However, ace editor is not set to full width of myeditor.

Comment: call editor.resize after changing the size of the container div.

Comment: Can you also style several editors via a class in CSS ?